# JS/Jquery force minimized window to open

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a certain event is triggered on my website, a Jquery modal opens with a mp3 sound notification to inform the user.

However, I also need:

1. My website's tab to become Active if more than 1 tab is opened
2. The browser to open itself automatically if it is minimized or in the background of another opened application/window

Nota: this should only be done once of course, then the user can come back to the other tab or window if any

How can these 2 points be achieved using JS/Jquery?

Comment: I don't think you can directly manipulate browser tabs unless you interface with a browser API as a plugin. [chrome.tabs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)  Firefox probably has something similar.  Additionally, if you do go for the extension path, you can also interface with the [chrome.notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) API to let users know that something has happened.

Comment: If you touch my tabs, I'll never visit your site again.

Comment: Can you imagine the havoc that spammers/marketers would wreck if there was a way for them to force their window into focus?

Comment: This window focus is used for experts to know when they have a client, not for spam purposes. The experts are the ones who asked us for this feature, so take it easy with the flashy one-liner answers: they are not of any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to turn to Your tab is a

```
confirm();
```

You can check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/YbtY9/

Enter and quickly change the tab to another.

Comment: It works, but stops the audio in the background; how can I prevent this?